# What is the relation between the case,workitem,document in case manager

Tags: dojo, ibm-case-manager

I am new to working on Case manager application. I just need to know the relation between the document, Case , workitem  and what it refers to understand the context of the above used in places of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In IBM Case Manager, a Case is technically implemented as a "CaseFolder". As it is a folder, it can contain subfolders and documents.

A case can also contain "Tasks". A task can best be seen as a "Workflow" that has one ore more "steps" that must be completed in order to complete the task. A WorkItem basically contains the properties (String, boolean,..) and content (in the form of references to documents) needed for the step.

Review the [Case management solution concepts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCTJ4_5.3.3/com.ibm.casemgmt.installing.doc/acmov005.htm) for more information on the Case-management concepts & terms, and the [IBM filenet p8 redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247667.pdf) chapter 2.3.2 on the concepts of Workflows&WorkItems.

Comment: Thanks for  the info Jonker